# can node-gyp "binding.gyp" file support .c extensions?

Tags: c, node-gyp

I am trying to write a nodejs addon that has dependencies on both C and C++ source files. However, if I modify the "binding.gyp" target/sources to include .c files, the Makefile generated in the ./build directory does not seem to recognize the .c extension. The .cc dependency works fine. Is there any way to declare C dependency in the binding.gyp file?